# how to list down or enumerate all the Query names under a MS Access Macro using VBA

Tags: database, ms-access, automation, vba

When we open a Macro in MS access in Design mode, we see all the queries (OpenQuery) and many other events can be there.I need to list down only the query names inside a macro. I know how to get all query names from the DB already, what I am specifically looking is, if I pass a macro name inside a function/sub in VBA it will list down only those queries inside it.

Like in the following image , there are three queries in the database. But "Macro1" packs two queries, so, if I want to get only those two query names by passing Macro1 as a parameter string in a function.

[image: Sample image]

Comment: I really appreciate dotNET, that you spent some time for my question to find a solution. But I am really sorry , if I am misunderstood, I already have enumerated all database objects whether its query or form or even list down all macro names. What i am struggling at is READING the Query names in a specific Macro" if i pass a specific macro name to a function , i only want to get the queries packed inside the macro, not any other macro.

Comment: Take a look at https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/462915-reading-microsoft-access-macros-via-vba-code  that link suggest there is no way to directly view components of the macro using VBA, but it discusses how to export all macros to a text file, then parsing the text file.

Comment: Thanks a lot Wayne!! I think you are right, I've also seen this before posting here while searching the answer for myself. Still thought if anyone here can answer it in a different way. Actually I have several accdbs containing many macros and queries. I have a strict timeline to convert the scripts into SAS. Manually if I open each macro and then open the queries one by one to convert into proc sql. It will be too monotonous and time consuming. So I wrote all the codes to get sql from a query and enumerated all queries, but i needed to write them sequentially that are placed in a macro.

Comment: I did some searching but did not find a way to automate the export to text, or to automate the 'convert to Visual Basic' feature. If you have a large number of macros, ouch!

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you need to read query names from macroses. If so, it's definitely possible. At least http://www.accessdependencychecker.com/ does this using VBA, you can download and check how it was done, software is free.

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn , ya 15 macros, each has 10 - 20 some queries. Writing manually as much as i can. my weekend is going to be ruined :D But after collating the queries, next part I managed to make automated. Converting msaccess sql into proc sql. all spaces replaced with '_' "Insert Into" repalced with create table as etc...lot of automation is built in vba to save tht time.

Comment: @SergeyS. Unfortunaely cant install third party addin in office laptop :( But good share for knowledge.. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @SergeyS. for pointing out the source code is in Access Dependency Checker!  I've used that tool for years and had never noticed...

I condensed the code found there to export each macro as a txt file. To run this, place this module in your database, change the 'sMacroFile' path to suit your environment.

And a huge thanks to Thomas Koester for providing Access Dependency Checker (http://www.accessdependencychecker.com/)!

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Function Process_Macros()
Dim mcr As Object
Dim sMacroFile  As String
    If CurrentProject.AllMacros.Count > 0 Then
        '--- cycle thru collection of macros
        For Each mcr In CurrentProject.AllMacros
            Debug.Print "Macro: " & mcr.Name
            sMacroFile = "c:\TEMP\" & mcr.Name & ".txt"
            ''''Call readMacro(ac, mcr)
            SaveAsText acMacro, mcr.Name, sMacroFile
        Next mcr
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: yes truly helpful!! Thanks a lot @Wayne and also @Sergey!! :)